# How to replace the mobile phone number in my Gmail account

Tags: google-account, account-management

I have my mobile phone number in my Gmail account and that number has been changed. How can l add the new number to this account?

Answer (score 7):

In Gmail go to **Settings and then select accounts** and scroll down to *Change Account Settings*.

Go to **Change password recovery options** in the 'Change account settings' section.

Click **Edit** next to the mobile phone number and simply edit the number

Click **Save** to make your changes.

Comment: also you can try : login into your gmail account and in new tab open accounts.google.com / https://www.google.com/settings/security [in the right hand side you will find the area to edit phone number]

Comment: This no longer is a viable answer. There is not edit next to the mobile phone number.