# How to change my Gmail account phone number

Tags: gmail

How do I change my phone number on my Gmail account on my new phone? I have forgotten my password and can’t change it because it sends a code to my old number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace the mobile phone number in my Gmail account](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45447/how-to-replace-the-mobile-phone-number-in-my-gmail-account)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, The only way you would be able to update the phone number is by you been logged on to your account.

I recommend using [Google Account Recovery tool](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/?ard=AHwGkRk5KZozw84MDahUUhMLgLCMCOSiJhJ-mD3BbamkQzxAUfQTrhlHHkjKL376Joy6IYTuJW_bEI1BDh7-V3iWM-uLsiJU_MKylfWfJA5-S_shcqqxx-r8SecIrB2DXHpsB4cDLt3kmgvBrWWx1wxkyttZ2PEpYg). You should be able to recover the account using one of your previous Gmail passwords and answering basic questions pertaining to the account. After you recover the account follow [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/183728?hl=en&ref_topic=2665222).