# How to change phone number in Google account?

Tags: google-account

I gave Google my phone number to verify it, not knowing that it would change it, and now my phone number is completely different? What have I done, and how do I unverify it and change my phone number back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace the mobile phone number in my Gmail account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45447/how-to-replace-the-mobile-phone-number-in-my-gmail-account)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to unverify your number. Just change your phone number and verify the new number.

Here is the way to change the phone number:

> You can edit information like your name, birthday, gender, and the email and phone number associated with your account. This basic information is used to help others get in touch with you more easily in products like Hangouts, Gmail, and Maps.
>
> 1. Sign in to **My Account**.
> 2. In the "Personal info & privacy" section, select **Your personal info**.
> 3. Choose the information you want to edit and follow the onscreen instructions.

[Edit your basic account information](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27442?hl=en).